# Responsive web site not vertically scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been building a site using a Bootstrap template, but have run into an issue of the site not being about to scroll vertically on a mobile device. The site works when viewing it on a laptop, however when I test it on a mobile device, I am unable to scroll to the page content vertically.

You can see a sample of the site here:
http://dennisshepherd.com/v3/index.html

I have been searching for an answer on the forums but have yet to find something that works. Thanks in advance for any help that you may provide!

Comment: (OT) It's just me or today every site looks just the same... (C) Hard to tell... this one will give you some few hours of happy debugging. Might be some overflow element wrapper that controls the parallax... might be html, body... might be in the forest!

Comment: Time to prove your debugging chops!

Comment: @d3signdude: Remove the errors, such as the malformed comment in the html. Uninstall skrollr. Try again. Also, the bootstrap-theme.css is not used in this design, waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: no, every site looks the same and it's getting boring.

Comment: No it's the script that is changing the native scroll bars. Remove it, it slows down the site and is always bad to do. And it could be the stellar, really slow

Comment: When I look at the console, I see: TypeError: $(...).niceScroll is not a function. Go into main.js line 135. Remove the "niceScroll" function and see what happens. Also - remove the malformed comment in the HTML as @Christina mentioned.

Comment: There's the niceScroll and the skrollr (which on mobile is not a good idea at all)

Comment: Yep, I recommend losing them both but "niceScroll" is causing a type error. The only reason it isn't breaking the page is that it is at the very end of main.js which is the last js external file to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed your problem. You needed to remove "Skroller", and "NiceScroll" from your main.js file.

[Here](http://www.worldonewebdesign.com/projects/uxtest/) you will find your website working fine on tablet/mobile (without some of your images that I didnt bother to source). [Here](http://www.worldonewebdesign.com/projects/uxtest/main.js) you will find the JavaScript that you need for your main.js file.

As a suggestion, when you use templates, check the web console for JavaScript Errors. This could really help you out down the road.

Also, I recommend you remove the references to these two items from your index.html file. You will find them near the bottom around line 500 or so.

EDIT: I had a bad link to the main.js. I have corrected it.